# Recently hacked by iskorpitx, strange upload form appears and cant get rid of it

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Have a site running drupal that was hacekd by iskorpitx.

After noticed the hack i update all (Core and modules)

Before update drupal core and modules i saw some strange files and also some on them were or was a trojans. i run an AV scan, delete all malware and then run drupal update.

Also, a strange upload form appears at the bottom of the page even after update all drupal core and modules. can someone give me a clue? Has anyone suffered from this?

Cant restore from backup because also backups are infected with the trojan. Make 5 backups per week every day but when i noticed it it was too late to recover from backup.

Cant give access to the site becasue i block it with a htpasswd so noone except for me can enter it.

Comment: Ouch... must be frustrating...

Comment: I finally find it... was pretty hidden `ob_start();
  print eval('?>' . $code);
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();`

DO NOT USE PHP FILTER MODULE PHP FILTER FORMATS AND SUCHS :(